# How to include php files with absolute file path set in php.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created a php.ini file and added the following line

```
include_path = ".:/home/my_cpanel_username/my_include_folder/"
```

I'm not sure how to reference/include the file in my page

is it enough to add the below line or is there a special syntax

```
<?php
include 'nav.php';
?>
```

This doesn't seem to work. I also tried setting the file path in .htaccess but it gives a internal error.

Comment: This should work. Are you sure your php.ini file is loaded? You can check that with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: And anyway, you should never rely on `include_path` as it kills the portability of your work. It's better to include files using paths relative to current file path (with `__DIR__`).